# Hiding website navbar in mobile browser breaks

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, nav

I'm currently building a site that has a fixed navbar that slides away to be hidden when the user scrolls down, when the user scrolls up the navbar then slides back down again, it works fine on desktop browsers but not in mobile. If the user scrolls down in a mobile browser the navbar hides as it should but then it either takes multiple scrolls upwards for it to appear or it just doesn't appear at all.

You can see the demo of the site here:
http://riley87.co.uk/velocity/

Here's the js:

```
var scroll_pos = 0;
var scroll_time;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    clearTimeout(scroll_time);
    var current_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (current_scroll >= $('#stickybar').outerHeight()) {
        if (current_scroll <= scroll_pos) {
            $('#stickybar').removeClass('hidden');    
        }
        else {
            $('#stickybar').addClass('hidden');  
        }
    }

    scroll_time = setTimeout(function() {
        scroll_pos = $(window).scrollTop();
    }, 0);
});
```

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: Works fine for me on Chrome and Firefox, mobile and not.  What mobile browser/device are you using?  PS - if that's your design it's very impressive, nice job.

Comment: Yes it is thank you! it doesn't work properly on both android and ios, if you try swiping up closer to the top when the navbar is hidden it should break.

Comment: I see what's happening.  You have the same problem I ran into.  Once you pass the height of the stickybar you start hiding/showing the bar but once your inside of that area the code won't run.  I'll put it in a jfiddle so you can see what to do easier.  http://jsfiddle.net/F8QYU/2/

Comment: Can't seem to get that working, now the navbar doesn't reappear at all. Here's the link to the markup: http://jsfiddle.net/fXwSb/